# Can ENUM be extended in an AVRO schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I think I am having issues getting a schema from my AVRO schema registry because I extended an ENUM in my AVRO schema.

Before

```
        "name": "eventType",
        "type":
        {
            "type": "enum",
            "name": "EventFilter",
            "symbols" : ["START", "PAUSE", "STOP", "RESUME", "END"]
        },
        "doc": "event type used for filtering in kafka consumer"
```

After

```
        "name": "eventType",
        "type":
        {
            "type": "enum",
            "name": "EventFilter",
            "symbols" : ["START", "PAUSE", "STOP", "RESUME", "END", "REDO", "UNDO"]
        },
        "doc": "event type used for filtering in kafka consumer"
```

Is it possible to do this? I am having an issue getting the schema which I have uploaded to my avro schema registry.

Comment: It's not backwards compatible, but that doesn't mean that you can't force the registry to accept the schema by disabling backwards checks

Comment: I then assume when I upload it is getting blocked because of backwards validation checks which I can not see the results of.  Would this property help  use.latest.version  Though I am concerned that other clients which are not updated will access that schema and have issues.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that property. But if you want clients to be able to interpret those new enums, then they'll have to upgrade. Otherwise, might make more sense to use a string field rather than an enum

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a default value. In this case the default would be used in case if enum value is unexpected in a reader schema.

See the spec here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Enums

Note: this feature was not available in earlier versions of avro.